# Vue.js v3 passing data through router link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an object in Portfolio.vue like this:

```js
data() {
        return {
            portfolio: {
                front: [
                     { description: '1. project ', src: require("../assets/sample.jpg"),  slug: 'first'},
                     { description: '2. project', src: require("../assets/sample.jpg"),  slug: 'second' },
                     { description: '3. project', src: require("../assets/sample.jpg"),  slug: 'third' },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Portfolio.vue:

```js
<div class="">
               <div  v-for="(data,index) in portfolio.front" :key="index"> 
            <router-link  :to="'/portfolio/'+data.slug">  <div class="element" :data-description="data.description">
                   <img :src="data.src " alt=""> 
               </div>          
            </router-link>
               </div>
 </div>
```

PortfolioProduct.vue

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <p>I want to take data to here. In here, i have to reach the data like this: portfolio.front.description</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: {

    },
}
</script>
```

My routes:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/portfolio",
    name: "Portfolio",
    component: Portfolio,
  },
  {
    path: "/portfolio/:id",
    name: "PortfolioProduct",
    component: PortfolioProduct,
    props: true,
  },
];
```

I want to take data from Portfolio.vue to PortfolioProduct.vue , i couldn't solve. I'm using vue js3 , if you help me i will be glad. Thank you

Comment: which data you want to take, just the slug or the whole object?

Comment: Object. not just the slug. For example in my object,  if the slug is 'first' , i have to reach { description: '1. project ', src: require("../assets/sample.jpg"),  slug: 'first'},
  all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the template literal, changing the router-link would be like so:

```
<router-link  :to="`/portfolio/${data.slug}`">  <div class="element" :data-description="data.description">
```

Comment: There is no error on my structure. I have to reach object from a component to other component. My structure is working, there is no syntax error